# Download trusted Certificate with InstallCert.java

Tags: java, security, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to add Trusted certificate for many web services deployed in localhost.
I find this article: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/
when you follow the steps in this article, the result will be  “jssecacerts” file.
In my case I have many servers:

1. server 1: http://localhost:8181
2. server 2: http://localhost:8282

So, I tried to generate 2 differents files called “jssecacerts_8181” and “jssecacerts_8282”. But this one doesn't work.

Does the name of the generated file must be "jssecacerts"?
 How can we add more than one trusted certificate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Do not change the jssecacerts file name. When you want add more than
  one trusted certificate you just copy jssecacert from the
  /jre/lib/security folder (if it is present) to different location .
- Then run Installcert.java file where jssecacerts file is present
  (InstallCert and jssecacerts are in same folder).
- Then that jssecacerts file put into the /jre/lib/security folder.

Note :  You can add more than one trusted certificate in same jssecacerts file 
Hope it will work .

Answer (score 3):

follow the detailed instructions explained below

https://github.com/escline/InstallCert

once Certificate was added to keystore,restart the tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the server SSL certificate and to add it to Java keystore.

For installation you could use InstallCert. InstallCert version 2 is available [here](https://github.com/joro88/InstallCert).

Detailed install instructions: [here](https://bghints.blogspot.com/2013/04/installing-root-and-intermediate.html)